# Fix-data-table - How to set table fluid width

Tags: facebook, reactjs

I'm trying to install the fluid-width table from facebok's fix-data-table plugin.

What doesn't work is the fluid part. It's not fluid. So what am I missing here?

the code

```
<div style={{width:'100%'}}>
    <Table
        rowHeight={50}
        rowsCount={10}
        width={2000}
        height={500}
        headerHeight={30}>
        <Column
        header={<Cell>First Name</Cell>}
        cell={<Cell>mama</Cell>}
        fixed={true}
        width={100}
        />
        <Column
        header={<Cell>Sentence! (flexGrow greediness=2)</Cell>}
        cell={<Cell>chacha</Cell>}
        flexGrow={2}
        width={200}
        />
        <Column
        header={<Cell>Company (flexGrow greediness=1)</Cell>}
        cell={<Cell>nana</Cell>}
        flexGrow={1}
        width={200}
        />
        <Column
        width={100}
        header={<Cell>Last Name</Cell>}
        cell={<Cell>sasa</Cell>}
        />
    </Table>
</div>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you have all 4 columns, but there exists a conflict between total width set as the attribute of `<Table />` component, and total sum of every `<Column />` width. Your table width is set as **2000**, but columns are: **100 + 200 + 200 + 100 = 600**. That makes 2-nd column very wide because it has `flexGrow` attribute set (3-rd column also has this attribute). `flexGrow` property takes any available extra width and distribute it proportionally according to all columns' flexGrow values.

**UPDATED:**
Actually, you must specify width for `<Table />` component. If you want a table to take all the available space of its parent container, than you can use a responsive-wrapper like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/responsive-fixed-data-table).

Comment: what are you suggesting to do in this case?

Comment: Change table width, or change `flexGrow` attributes.

Comment: change the table width to ? I tried 1000, 1200. none of that work. I'm uploading the screenshot I will paste here in a momemnt

Comment: 100 + 200 + 200 + 100 = 600, so try to change it to 600 :)

Comment: I tried that 600 as well, still not working. Here is the screenshot of 600

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/30agz421gb12urn/Screen%20Shot%202016-07-15%20at%205.49.19%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Ok, what result do you expect to get?

Comment: the table should expand to the width of viewport. ex: if viewport width is 2000 the table width should be 2000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117409/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-angry-kiwi).

Comment: As the table on recieve fixed px value, so setting percentage won't help. After some digging, I realize using extra code to detect the parent width and pass it to the table is a feasible way to archive this.